# Minor usability tweak for new reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, usability, reputation-graph

The new reputation graph rocks. Totally.

There's just one minor tweak (twEEK?) that could improve it - I've seen that you can select a new range in the bottom graph, but instinctively what I tried to do first was grab the block representing the current window and slide it. It too me a few micro-seconds of WTF to work it out.

*Viva la rivoluzione!* :)

Comment: The drag seems to currently only work in IE, not Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @aBitObvious what version of Chrome are you using? It works fine on 10.0.648.204 in Win7.

Comment: @Jarrod: Chrome is 10.0.648.151 and Safari is 5.0.4.  I'll try upgrading to the latest for both.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jarrod: The drag does work in all 3.  The problem wasn't the version (I upgraded to the latest).  In Chrome and Safari, drag doesn't work if the page zoom is not 100% (I had it at 150%).  In IE, drag works regardless of zoom level.  I think this is a browser issue rather than a problem with the graph.

Comment: Be careful what you call a tweak. :) I think typo and text counts as tweek, but there are several (hidden) considerations from a programming perspective that apply to this graph request and are necessary to avoid an annoying bug. (Let me know if I am wrong. I am just imagining how I would write something like that. I know almost nothing about how this graph works.) (+1 by the way)